# Dataframe: Finding 2 consecutive quarters of GDP decline to find recession start

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find 2 consecutive quarters of GDP decline to find the recession start. The dataframe is as follows:

```
Quarter GDP(2009 Unchained)
2000q1     20
2000q2     19
2000q3     18
2000q4     17
2001q1     16
2001q2     17
2001q3     18
2001q4     19
```

I have written the following code:

```
def start()
GDP.columns = ['Quarter', 'GDP (2009 chained)']
    GDP = GDP.set_index('Quarter')
    #GDP['Quarterly Change'] = GDP['GDP (2009 chained)'].diff()
    
    for index in GDP.index:
        first_q = GDP.loc[index, 'GDP (2009 chained)']
        second_q = GDP.loc[index+1, 'GDP (2009 chained)']
        third_q = GDP.loc[index+2, 'GDP (2009 chained)']
        if (second_q < first_q) and (third_q < second_q): start = first_q
    
    return start
```

but I am getting this error:

```
---> 16         second_q = GDP.loc[index+1, 'GDP (2009 chained)']
     17         third_q = GDP.loc[index+2, 'GDP (2009 chained)']
     18         if (second_q < first_q) and (third_q < second_q): start = first_q

TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Presumably because you cannot +1 to the index as the index is a string label not integer - how can I correct my code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Quarter': ['2000q1', '2000q2', '2000q3', '2000q4', '2001q1', '2001q2', '2001q3', '2001q4'],
                  'GDP(2009 Unchained)': [20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 17, 18, 19]})
print(df)

  Quarter  GDP(2009 Unchained)
0  2000q1                   20
1  2000q2                   19
2  2000q3                   18
3  2000q4                   17
4  2001q1                   16
5  2001q2                   17
6  2001q3                   18
7  2001q4                   19
```

A continuous set of trues indicate the recession period

```
df['Recession'] = (df['GDP(2009 Unchained)']>df['GDP(2009 Unchained)'].shift(-1)) & (df['GDP(2009 Unchained)'].shift(-1)>df['GDP(2009 Unchained)'].shift(-2))
print(df)

  Quarter  GDP(2009 Unchained)  Recession
0  2000q1                   20       True
1  2000q2                   19       True
2  2000q3                   18       True
3  2000q4                   17      False
4  2001q1                   16      False
5  2001q2                   17      False
6  2001q3                   18      False
7  2001q4                   19      False
```